# Iterate over columns in a row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with following headers

```
question_no,question,A,B,C,D
```

where A,B,C,D are options for a question. The number of options for a question can vary from file to file(for eg. 4 - A,B,C,D 6 - A,B,C,D,E,F). I am trying to get the values of options in the row using the following code.

```
data = pd.read_csv(request.FILES['myfile'])
optioncodes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
col_nos = len(data.columns)
opt_lmt = col_nos - 2

for (idx, row) in data.iterrows():
             print(row.question_no)
             for j in range(opt_lmt):
                print(row.optioncodes[j])
```

but I am getting the error

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'optioncodes'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't have a column called 'optioncodes' in the dataframe, so the error is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot accessor (`df.col_name` or `serie.index_value`) is only a shortcut for the named element accessor (`df['col_name']` or `serie['index_value']`). And it is only valid at 2 conditions:

- the name must be a constant - while you want it to be a variable
- the name must be a valid identifier (no space or special character)

What you want here is just:

```
         ...
         for j in range(opt_lmt):
            print(row[optioncodes[j]])
```